# Vertical Scroll Bars in Group By View

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, grouping

I am looking to add a scroll bar to replace the 1-15 per page view. Is this possible to put a vertical scroll bar instead of having the 1-15 option? If so how do I go about doing this?

I currently have this in as a document library, web part on a Team Site page.

Screenshot provided below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the item limit on the document library view.

Modify View, scroll to 'Item Limit' and change  from 15 to a higher number.